# Current vs Voltage Drive for Loudspeakers

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-current, voltage

Please see this article:

[here](http://www.current-drive.info/6)

I don't know enough EMFT to comment on this but I am working on other tasks for a wireless speaker system prototype called "Busker's Friend".  Completing my Schaum's EMFT book is on my list.

So please comment on the truth or invalidity of this article and give an explanation.  Thank you!

This is physics related and I have a good reason for not posting on electronics.stackexchange.  So please be kind.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Nelson Pass (of "Pass Labs") has produced some 'current source' amplifiers with his "First Watt" line.  You can read some about it here:  http://www.firstwatt.com/pdf/art_cs_amps.pdf

Comment: Could you comment on the accuracy of "Current vs Voltage" drive, and "Current drive" *is* better and why?  Thanks.  You could make a simple answer and I will select it.  Thank you.

Comment: "Better"?  By what objective criteria?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  well, some distortion % measurements are used in the first article I linked above, or in a sidebar link on that article.  The current-source amp had less "distortion".  Again, I am a GD newbie, so I'm looking for a little spoon feeding but not much.  I am just wondering if these articles are bullshit or DO have some validity.  Since I will be designing the amplifier output stage for these wireless mini speaker cabinets.  And naturally I would like the best possible sound reproduction (using a class-D amp).

Comment: @AlfredCentauri (continued) The design is already sending the sound wirelessly & lossless using TI's PurePath audio chips.  So we've already gotten rid of cable noise and the need for nice cables.

Comment: This question (v1) seems off-topic. Despite what OP writes in the question formulation (v1), this seems to belong on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Um... why do you keep saying (v1) ?  Thx.

Comment: v1 = version 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the article http://www.edn.com/design/consumer/4423155/Loudspeaker-operation--The-superiority-of-current-drive-over-voltage-drive
of  Esa Merilainen "The most remarkable thing here regarding loudspeakers is that the voltage between the ends of the wire does not appear anywhere in these equations. That is, the speaker driver in the end obeys only current, not caring what the voltage across the terminals happens to be." 
So far so good, but then he writes that "There cannot be found any scientifically valid reasons that justify the adoption of voltage as the control quantity - it is only due to the historical legacy originated almost a century ago, most likely by cheapness and simplicity; the quality and physical soundness of operation have not been considerations in this choice." and that is just not true. 
There is a very good reason for having voltage the control variable for a loudspeaker and that is because the impedance of a loudspeaker is a large inductance with some loss and motional capacitance. It is inductive below the resonant frequency and inductive again above the frequency of $|Z_{min}|$. True enough, in between those frequencies it is capacitive but a charge pump (controlled current source) will have a tough time to push and pull currents through the impedance that is mostly inductive.

Comment: Thank you thank you!  So the article is partially BS.  Means I will have to come back to it in a few months and see for myself.  Maybe even build two prototypes of my speaker cabinets and see for myself - one with voltage out and one with one more stage of voltage-to-current.

Comment: I would not go that far, am just calling your attention to some difficulties you may encounter. Good luck with the prototypes!